# React Router Native(4.3.0) Url Params break app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-v4

I've got a React Native project which I'm using react-router-native version 4.3.0.

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <NativeRouter>
        <Base user={this.state.user} >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Splashstart}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
            <Route exact path="/report/:id" component={Report}/>
          </View>
        </Base>
      </NativeRouter>
    </Provider>
```

I've got my app wrapped in a Base component which basically decides if it needs to show a Nav or not, if there is a User.

```
render() {
if(this.props.user) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
      <Nav />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

}

When I hit the Report Route, the Nav becomes useless and I am stuck in the page. It seems to smash my routes.

It can be any route if it has a parameter on the url (:id). I tried rendering just a piece of text, and it still happened - so I don't think it's anything in the page.

My `<Nav />` compnent in the base re-renders on every page refresh, as does the base, I'd expect base too as the children change, but shouldn't Nav remain?

this.state.user doesn't change when passed to the base component.

Any help would be epic!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Route` component has a typo: the extra `extract` prop.

```
<Route exact path="/report/:id" component={Report}/>
```

Comment: Cheers for the response, though the exact prop just means that /report wont respond, but report/:id will. I gave it a go and removed it, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. I had a vague souvenir of the exact prop, turns out I was wrong.

Is there any chance you could add an excerpt of the Report component?